# Insert list as singular value in postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I use sqlalchemy engine for insertion data in postgresql table. I won't to insert list in one row as if list be a string with many value.

```
query = text('INSERT INTO table (list_id, list_name) VALUES ({}, {}) RETURNING'.format(my_list,'list_name'))
result_id = self.engine.execute(query)
```

when i tried execute my code I received error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "["
LINE 1: ...INTO table (list_id, list_name) VALUES (['str1...                                                             ^

[SQL: INSERT INTO table (list_id, list_name) VALUES (['str1', 'str1', 'str1'], 'list_name') RETURNING id]
```

I tried to represent my list as str(my list) but result was same. Also i try  str(['str1', 'str1', 'str1']).replace('[', '{').replace(']', '}')

My table query:

```
CREATE TABLE api_services (
                  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                  list_id VARCHAR,
                  list_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
                  );
```